# Finding the number of inversions in an Array

Tags: algorithm, scala

I am doing a college assignment where I have to count the number of inversions in an array/list. An inversion is defined as a tuple where `i<j and a[i]>a[j]`. For example in this array

```
val arr = Array(3, 1, 2, 4)
```

The inversions are (3,1), (3,2). So total count of inversions is 2.

I wrote a divide and conquer algorithm to find this. it works for small arrays. but for large inputs like this one

https://github.com/abhsrivastava/ArrayInversions/blob/master/src/main/resources/inversions.txt

there is always an out of memory error. My code is below

```
import scala.io.Source
import Sort._

object CountInversions extends App {
  val data = Source.fromResource("inversions.txt").getLines.map(_.toInt).toList
  val inversions = countInversions(data)
  println(s"number of inversions ${inversions}")

  def countInversions(input: List[Int]): Int = {
    input match {
      case Nil => 0
      case List(a) => 0
      case _ =>
        val mid = input.size / 2
        val left = input.slice(0, mid)
        val right = input.slice(mid, input.size)
        val l1 = countInversions(left)
        val l2 = countInversions(right)
        val l3 = splitInversions(left, right)
        l1 + l2 + l3
    }
  }

  // assuming l1 and l2 are almost of same size.
  // total complexity 2(nlogn + n)
  def splitInversions(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]): Int = {
    val sortedL1 = mergeSort(l1) // nlogn
    val sortedL2 = mergeSort(l2) // nlogn
    (sortedL1, sortedL2) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => 0
      case (Nil, _) => 0
      case (_, Nil) => 0
      case (_, _) if sortedL1.head > sortedL2.head =>
        val result = splitInversions(sortedL1, sortedL2.tail)
        sortedL1.size + result
      case (_, _) =>
        splitInversions(sortedL1.tail, sortedL2)
    }
  }
}
```

I am not posting the code for mergeSort here. it is just a simple merge sort.

My objective is to be able to determine the inversions in O(nlogn) time and be able to process the large file. I also want to keep my code functional.

How can I optimize my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I've noticed.

1. You use `List` to represent the input data. Lists are inefficient (linear) for things like `input.size` (which you do twice on the same input) and `input.slice()`.
2. Both `countInversions()` and `splitInversions()` are recursive but they're not tail recursive, so that's going to eat up stack space.
3. `splitInversions()` sends its passed parameters to `mergeSort()` which means that every time it calls itself (recurses) it re-sorts already sorted data.
4. Your calculations return an `Int`, which is going to be too small for a large data set such as the `inversions.txt` you've linked to.

But generally I find the whole thing rather too complicated.

Here's an alternative algorithm that is smaller, faster, and more memory efficient.

```
def countInversions(input :Vector[Int]) :Long = {
  val idxBuf = input.indices.sortBy(input).toBuffer
  input.indices.foldLeft(0L){ case (sum,x) =>
    val idx = idxBuf.indexOf(x)
    idxBuf.remove(idx)  //side effect
    sum + idx
  }
}
```